# Insertar PHP MySQl un objeto del tipo DATETIME

Tags: php, datetime

Quiero insertar en mi BBDD una variable que sea del **tipo DATETIME** para poder realizar SELECT ordenados por fechas según los valores que se insertaron en la BBDD.

La fecha la recibo en la variable **$fInicio** y viene con foramto dd/mm/yyyy por eso hago un *date con strtotime* para cambiar a yyyy/mm/dd que es lo qye necesita datetime.

La hora se recibe en la variable $hinicio con formato hh:mm y la paso con date y strtotime a hh.mm:ss.

En el log del servidor me sale este error:

> PHP Recoverable fatal error:  Object of class DateTime could not be
> converted to string on line $sql->bindParam(':date', $date);

Y este es mi código:

```
$dia= date("Y/m/d", strtotime($fInicio));
$hora = date("h:i:s", strtotime ($hInicio.':00'));
$date = new DateTime($dia.' '.$hora);
$sql->bindParam(':date', $date);
```

¿Alguien sabe como solucinar el error?

GRACIAS!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu caso `$date` sería un objeto `DateTime`, y el método `bindParam` no admite este tipo objetos, por lo que **tendrás que pasar la fecha como una cadena formateada válida**. Para ello puedes usar `format()`.

Además, no hace falta marear tanto la cosa (pasar por varias funciones para crear una fecha), puedes crear una cadena con tu fecha y hora sin más y construir el objeto mediante el método: [`createFromFormat()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php) el cual te da una flexibilidad enorme, como podrás ver en los ejemplos del Manual de PHP.

Atento a la diferencia entre el uso de `h` y `H`. Si tus horas tienen formato 24 horas debes usar la `H` mayúscula. Dado que al parecer los segundos serán siempre `0` simplemente ignoramos el dato en la creación del objeto. Revisa el enlace anterior, donde está explicado el significado de cada formato.

Con esto debería bastar:

```
#OJO a la H (mayúscula) que es para formato 24 horas
$mFormat="Y/m/d H:i";
$mDate = DateTime::createFromFormat($mFormat, "$fInicio $hInicio");
$strDate= $mDate->format($mFormat);
$sql->bindParam(':date', $strDate);
```

---

Si no necesitas un objeto `DateTime` en este contexto, puedes insertar la cadena directamente, dado que en este caso, por los formatos que usas, parece que tu cadena ya viene con un formato válido para la base de datos:

```
$strDate= "$fInicio $hInicio:00";
$sql->bindParam(':date', $strDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

ya econtré la solución, espero le sirva a alguien:

```
$dia= date("Y/m/d", strtotime(str_replace("/","-",$fInicio)));
$hora = date("H:i:s", strtotime ($hInicio.':00'));
$dateNew = date_create_from_format("Y/m/d H:i:s", $dia." ".$hora)->format("Y/m/d H:i:s");

$sql->bindParam(':date', $dateNew);
```

Comment: Aquí usas 5 funciones para crear tu fecha/hora. Con `createFromFormat()` no necesitas nada de eso. Puedes crear la cadena de fecha directamente desde dicho método. E incluso, si no necesitas un objeto `DateTime` (otros usos en el mismo contexto) puedes pasar esa cadena sin más a `bindParam()`.

Comment: gracias por la informacion